# Best method to save and display blog content in reactjs and flutter using Laravel and MySQL as backend

Tags: reactjs, flutter, blogs

We are in planning phase of a blog portal. We decided to do it in reactjs for web, flutter for mobile and Laravel,MySQL as backend. We want to know which is the best method to read, save and display the content both in reactjs and flutter. There will be images, videos, links, headings, bold, italic...

Comment: React-native is the best fit for your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Both platform are best for achieve your requirement, but decision is on you which platform you pick for your project. I have been using both of framework,but i like flutter with rocking.